# Issues with converting between "string" "const unsigned char" and "utf8proc_uint8_t"

Tags: c++

Maybe a simple issue, but I've gotten confused between "byte arrays", pointers and casts in c++.

Take a look at the following and let me know what I need to read about to fix it, as well as the fix. It relates to the utf8proc library.

```
const unsigned char *aa = (const unsigned char*)e.c_str();
utf8proc_uint8_t* a = utf8proc_NFC(aa);
char b = (char)a;
string d = string(b);
```

It is bad enough no need for an error message here, but there is no constructor string on the string(b) line.

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be fixed? What is broken about it exactly? Does it compile? Does it run? Are there any errors reported? You need to be more specific. If your only problem is `string(b)` and assuming `string` refers to `std::string`, then it does not have a constructor that accepts a single `char` as input, but it does have other constructors you can use for that same purpose, such as `string(&b, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be a couple problems here.  The biggest is the assignment:

```
char b = (char)a;
```

What you are doing is telling the compiler to take the pointer (memory location) and convert that to a char, then assign it to single char value b.  So you'll basically have random jibberish in b.

Instead, if you want to treat a like a basic char*, you would write:

```
char* b = (char*)a;
```

Then you could use the string class with either:

```
string d = string(b);
```

or you could skip several line by the direct conversion:

```
string d = string((char*)a);
```

You are also looking for a headache down the line if you don't delete the conversion value returned by the utf8proc_NFC() call, and if you don't do an error check after the conversion.

Plus I'll put in a plug for using some Hungarian notation to distinguish a pointer (a 'p' prefix on variables).  This makes it obvious that you can do things like:

```
char tmp = *pStr;     // a single character (first in the string)
char tmp2 = pStr[1];  // a single character (second in the string)
char* pTmp = pStr;    // a pointer to a null terminated string
```

But you would never see:

```
char tmp3 = (char)pStr;     // compiles, but makes no sense to treat pointer as a character.
```

So here is a clean version of all of this:

```
utf8proc_uint8_t* pUTF = utf8proc_NFC( (const unsigned char*)e.c_str() );
string strUTF;
if (pUTF)
{
   strUTF = (char*)pUTF;
   free pUTF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is almost certainly not what you want, since it is casting a pointer into a scalar.

```
utf8proc_uint8_t* a = ...;
char b = (char)a;
```

Instead, you want to cast and produce a *pointer*:

```
utf8proc_uint8_t* a = ...;
const char *b = (const char *)a;
```

I also added `const`, which is not strictly necessary but a good idea to use wherever you can.